# I'm getting weird traffic from flipboard.com - is it referral spam?

Tags: google-analytics, spam, google-analytics-spam

Here's the screenshot:
[image: Flipboard.com referral traffic]

I have looked through several "referral spam" websites lists, but I didn't find flipboard.com on any of them. But from the stats (visit time, bounce rate), I'd say this is a spammy website too?

Answer (score 2):

Is your website available on the Flipboard magazine app? If it is, it might be visitors reading your posts from the app who then decide to continue to read  it directly on your website for a better view. In such cases most visitors will hit the back button to go back to the app after reading the post on your website, hence the high bounce rate.

Answer (score 0):

Try **checking the hostname it uses if it is not yours**, for example, the domain of your website.

If it's not one of your hostnames (you can compare with other referrals) or the hostname is **not set**, most probably is a referrer spam.

To check the hostname of a referral:

> - Go to the **Reporting** Tab in GA
> - Expand *Acquisition* > *All Traffic* > **Referrals**
> - Click on **secondary dimension** (top of your report)
> - Find and select **Hostname**

Comment: That referrer spam still sets hostnames as of May 2015 -- unless of course they upped their bots to actually crawl now :)